# OnClick redirect to a particular section of my website in Php

Tags: php, html, forms

My HTML:

```
<div class=" col-sm-7 slideanim text-center ">
  <div class="row text-center">
  <h4 class="text-center"><b>Fill the details and we'll get back to you within 6 business hours. <br>
  * - Required</b></h4><i>
    <form action="mail_handler.php" method="post" name="form" class="formfont">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">   
        <input type="text" name="name" class="inp form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Name*" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">

        <input type="email" name="email" class="inp form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email*" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">

        <input type="tel" name="phone" class="inp form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Phone*" required="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">

        <input type="text" name="college" class="inp form-control" placeholder="College/University*" required="">

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
        <textarea name="msg" class="msg-box form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Message Here...(Optional)"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="sub-btn">
        <br>
          <br>
    </form>
  </i></div>

  </div>
```

MailHandler php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $college=$_POST['college'];
    $msg=$_POST['msg'];

    $to='mailtosemicolon@gmail.com'; // Receiver Email ID, Replace with your email ID
    $subject='Form Submission';
    $message="Name :".$name."\n"."Phone :".$phone."\n"."Wrote the following :"."\n\n".$msg;
    $headers="From: ".$email;

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        echo "<h1>Sent Successfully! Thank you"." ".$name.", We will contact you shortly!</h1>";

    }
    else{
        echo "Something went wrong! Please try back sometime later";
    }
}?>
```

I am designing a web page which has 3 sections in it, namely section 1, section 2, and section 3 respectively. So, in section 3, i have a form and given its action as php file[MailHandler.php], which actually gets details from the form and sends a mail to my personal mail once the submit button(inside the form) is clicked.

Is there any way to redirect to section 3, when the details are successfully sent to my mail id, and display a success message below my submit button in the form

Comment: Please show some example code of what you have tried.

Comment: `<section id="s3">` ... then after the mail is sent in PHP `header('Location: page.php#s3');` ?

Comment: @CD001 in your case the message will also be visible before you submit

Comment: I have added my code as image file..

Comment: @BrentThierens - if you weren't doing anything else, true. I was just giving an example of how to use a fragment to jump to another part of the page using a header redirect.

Comment: @DurairajSaro ... don't add code as images please, it's not terribly useful for anyone attempting to debug it :| Post the actual code into the question.

Comment: @CD001 Added my codes in the question. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: @RonnieOosting I have added my codes. Thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you stay in section 3, there is no need for a redirect. I would solve this in Javascript.

What you can do is replace the submit button with a normal button. When clicked, you use Javascript to generate an ajax request to the server, like your submit would do. With the return code or custom return data, you can insert the response using Javascript below your form.
If you are using JQuery, you can quickly generate the form data like this:

```
$('form').serialize()
```

An ajax request has a `done` or `success` method which you can use. See this example: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Answer (score 0):

There can be two approaches to your problem.

The first one is to use, JavaScript. By this way, you can submit the contact form to your PHP script and then show the response message without even reloading the page, the tutorial can be found [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form).

The second method is when you submit the contact form to PHP, then using PHP you can redirect back to your HTML page with a section id appended in your URL, something like `http://www.example.com/index.html#section3`, where `section3` is the ID of your section.

Comment: The second approach will make the section visible even before submit, since the page before and after is the same.